# Maven profile not seeing dependency in child module

Tags: java, maven

I have searched over SO and Internet, but no success. This is what I have in short:

Multimodule project with dev and appserv profile. When dev profile is used (just `mvn clean install` because default=true), then load specific dependencies. One dependency is `Child-A` that must be loaded in `Child-B`. I am building always from parent `POM`.

I have profile defined in parent `POM` with activation and in `Child-B` I have same profile with dependencies.

This is my parent `POM`:

```
<project ..>
    <groupId>com.organisation</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>child-b</module>
        <module>child-a</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <javax.ws.rs.version>2.0</javax.ws.rs.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- project dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>child-a</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- build dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.ws.rs.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>child-a</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${javax.ws.rs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>app-server</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>app-server</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

My `Child-B` module that calls `Child-A`, the IDE as well when building `Child-B` doesn't see `Child-A`'s classes.

```
<project ..>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.organisation</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-b</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>child-a</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>app-server</id>
                <dependencies>
                    ...
                </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I don't see what is wrong here and can't understand where the problem is, why `Child-B` doesn't take `Child-A` as dependency. In parent `POM` inside `profile` I have tried to remove the `dependencyManagement`, but the result was still same - `Child-A` not seen in `Child-B` module. Apparently without the profiles everything was working fine.

Comment: is the last POM the POM of child-A or child-B?  You mentioned in your text that child-B have child-A as dependency, but the POM itself is having child-B as dependency

Comment: @AdrianShum hey, i fixed the type. Last POM is the Child-B, and inside profile I include child-a, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Skyzer: While it is possible to define dependencies in a `<profile/>`, it's generally not a good idea to be using this, as it may break portability and things will not be apparent. Furthermore, reports from a `dependency:tree` will only show the dependencies which are defined in the `pom.xml` and the activated profile, meaning they will cover just one of the cases. This is generally poor design and making projects inherit this way of doing things is like spreading the disease. (Just my 5 cents of advice).

Comment: @carlspring Okay, but how would i design then? For example I need to have separate builds for testing locally and for application server. In my application server some dependencies should be marked as provided, because Glassfish already has jax-rs and my child-a dependency is a shared lib in Glassfish. So and when building by default for testing locally these dependencies should be included in scope

Comment: quite some way to solve.  The one I suggest is to split them into several projects.  e.g. have a MAIN project that contains your main code. A WEB project that create WAR for app server which depends on the MAIN, and then another LOCAL project which build executable JAR which also depends on MAIN.  Another way is to make use of assembly plugin, and create different assemblies, each with different classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Child-b you put a dependency to child-b instead of a dependency to child-a

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>child-b</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>child-a</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answering, but it was a typo when I posted here the question with example POMs. My architecture is initially already as you suggest, and the problem is still unsolved